# Trying to use Bert (R add-on for Excel) with auto.arima not working

Tags: r, excel, bert-language-model

I'm using Bert (R add on for Excel).

When I try to run the following:

```
sales <- sample(100:170, 4*10, replace = TRUE)
advertising <- sample(50:70, 4*10, replace = TRUE)
sales_ts <- ts(sales, frequency = 4, end = c(2017, 4))
fit <- forecast::auto.arima(sales_ts, xreg = advertising,d=1,ic=c("aic"))
```

The `arima` works.

But when I try to use `auto.arima`

```
fit.arima <- arima(sales_ts,xreg =advertising,order=c(3,1,1))
```

I get the following error:

`Error in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")) :  number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)`

Please help!

Comment: Error messages alone are not always sufficient. Please add some reproducible code to better help others properly debug.

Comment: Hey @DeoluA, 

oh sure!

I am running this code in Bert:

```sales <- sample(100:170, 4*10, replace = TRUE)
advertising <- sample(50:70, 4*10, replace = TRUE)
sales_ts <- ts(sales, frequency = 4, end = c(2017, 4))
fit <- forecast::auto.arima(sales_ts, xreg = advertising,d=1,ic=c("aic"))```

so arima is working in bert but not auto.arima
```fit.arima <- arima(sales_ts,xreg =advertising,order=c(3,1,1))```

Comment: I've edited your question to include the code block you just supplied (in case of future questions, please be sure to include them initially)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run this in `R` itself, and faced no issues (it worked fine).

Based on your error message, it's possible there's a namespace/library clash causing this, or that one of your libraries/packages wasn't installed properly.

You can either:

- remove the package(s)

Use `find.package("insert package name here")` to find its location, then `remove.packages("insert package name here")` to remove it. Re-install and proceed

- add the package name itself when referencing the function, like you did with `forecast`, e.g.

```
# adding "stats" in front, if that's the package being used
fit.arima <- stats::arima(sales_ts,xreg =advertising,order=c(3,1,1))
```